# Unorthodox copy table data from one table to another

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, ms-access, c#-4.0

My scenario is that I have [mostly] matching tables in 2 different databases. The table schema will usually be identical, but sometimes will change (column additions, renames, removals). I need to copy data from Source to Destination under the following conditions:

- Attempt to insert all rows from source to destination. No updates.
- Unique constraints will cause inserts to fail for dups - this is OK
- If columns don't quite match up between source and dest, insert must still succeed. Yes, this is the tricky part. Wherever columns match, need insert according to matching schema. Any columns that are new/removed/renamed can be skipped and ignored, but overall insert must succeed.
- Source may be Access or MSSQL and Dest may be Access or MSSQL, so any sql must work for both.
- This is not a one-time thing. It's part of a software/data upgrade process that will occur over and over for many customers, with different datasets and different tables. But again, most columns will always match (table names will always be same on both sides, with similar schema), with occasional column differences and unique constraints.
- It's OK for an insert to fail due to a unique constraint violation (this means there's a duplicate record).
- It's NOT OK for an insert to fail due to column mismatches -- I need to find a way for these to match up best as possible. Unmatching columns can be skipped/ignored.
- Unfortunately the table schemas weren't designed very well and thus tables do not have an int primary key. Many tables have multi-column keys, but these can't be used because ANY table in the source may need to be copied to ANY table in the destination. So reliance on keys won't work.
- I'm using Visual Studio 2015 and latest c#. SQL Server and Access.

This is a strange scenario, but I need a robust way to handle it. I don't care if it's an ugly hack, it just needs to work. Can anyone think of a good approach for this?

Comment: I'd be writing my own logic in C# with ADO.NET to copy the intersection set of the columns in the source and destination tables. The other requirements can be met the same way. You can find out what the keys are. Maybe you'd need to set up mappings by hand for some match ups and save them in XML. This looks kinda fun.

Comment: Why are not using SSIS(SQlserver integration services) ? then use it in jobs so you can schedule it also. it has all the capabilities that you listed here.

Comment: I would use Access for this, to be able to transfer data between Access and MSSQL with SQL. **Link** source and target tables, get list of matching columns, build INSERT statement from that and run it. Pretty straightforward.

Answer (score -1):

I did project couple of years ago i had the same challenge.In my case there were multiple remote stores that they were offline during the month (no internet connection) and each 2 weeks they need to connect to internet and sync the data between their local database and HQ database.
Basically first they have to send their local data to HQ and then they need to receive HQ changes back.
If you dont have large data (in my case the database had more than 600 tables and around 60 million rows) you can first  send the client data to server merge with existing data then you can drop the client table and batch insert fresh data from server.